# Promotheus not able to read metrics from custom Rest Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus

I'm trying to get Promotheus to take metrics exposed via a custom Spring Boot Endpoint.
I have metrics in a file

```
# HELP cpu_usage_total The total amount of CPU.
# TYPE cpu_usage_total gauge.
cpu_usage_total 0.24950100481510162
# HELP memory_usage_total The total amount of MEMORY.
# TYPE memory_usage_total gauge.
memory_usage_total 30.0
```

I created a Restful endpoint to read from this file and expose its contents on port 8080 . Here's what I tried so far :

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/metrics")
    public void metrics(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/var/log/logparsing");
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("text", "plain", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream myStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        // Set the content type and attachment header.
        response.setContentType("text/plain; version=0.0.4;charset=utf-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        // Copy the stream to the response's output stream.
        IOUtils.copy(myStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
```

My promotheus.yaml config file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

  external_labels:
   monitor: 'codelab-monitor'
scrape_configs:
   - job_name: 'prometheus'
   scrape_interval: 5s
   metrics_path: '/metrics' 

   static_configs:
    - targets: ['logparsing:8080']
```

From what I read from the prometheus documentation is that the server expects data in this [format](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md)
 . I tried to respect it as much as I can but promotheus is not picking it up.

Any help would be appreciated , thank you .
PS: I cannot use the java client for Prometheus , It needs to be done this way.

Comment: Why do you store metrics in a static file? Metrics a supposed to evolve. As you are using spring boot, you can add `spring-boot-actuator`+ `micrometer-registry-prometheus` in your classpath, spring-boot will then automatically configure and expose a /prometheus endpoint that will have all those metrics.

Comment: I tottaly agree with you that this would be the much better approach but I have to implement it this way .. I'm pretty sure it's feasible .

Comment: Can you provide your response body? Is it the same as the original file?

Comment: Yes , it's the same as in the file.

Comment: You can also share your prometheus config file, so that we can check if the job is well set up. Does your job point to the good IP:HOST/metrics ?

Comment: I edited my question with the config file , Yes it is pointing I have tried it by setting micrometer and actuator and it's working fine for that data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229752/discussion-between-philippe-simo-and-mustapha-geribi).

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your environment and it seems your metrics were not valid due to `\r` characters at the end of lines.

I got this first:
[image]

Then I removed the comments:

Without the comments
[image: Invalid Syntax]

I've removed all `\r` characters from the file and that worked.
[image]
PS: Some editors add `\r` automatically, I used Notepad++ to edit the file.